# How to Add +200ms to css animation-duration on click jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

There is a div with css animation

```
.mydiv {
    animation: ticker 2000ms linear 0s infinite normal none running;
}
```

The `animation-duration` property is set to 2000ms
and im trying to change the speed of the animation with jquery
for example adding 200ms to the currentvalue

something like

```
$( "#speedup" ).click(function() {
 var mydiv = $( ".mydiv" );
 var val = mydiv.css('animation-duration');
 $(".mydiv").css("animation-duration", val + "ms")+200;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable 'val' is not an integer (2s). You can't multiply with this value. You need to use parseInt() to return the integer (2).

```
$('#speedup').click(function(){

       var mydiv = $( ".mydiv" );
       var val = mydiv.css('animation-duration');
       var newVal = (parseInt(val) * 1000); //parseInt(val) creates the integer 2. Multiply with 1000 to get 2000

       mydiv.css({"animation-duration" : newVal - 200 + "ms"});

 });
```

**Edit:** ParseFloat is even better. This way you can use toFixed to get the integer with 2 decimals.

https://jsfiddle.net/qcajbtz8/

```
$('#speedup').click(function(){

                var mydiv = $( ".mydiv" );
                var val = mydiv.css('animation-duration');
                var newVal = (parseFloat(val).toFixed(2) * 1000);

                mydiv.css({"animation-duration" : newVal - 200 + "ms"});

            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
    var val = currentvalue;
    $( "#speedup" ).click(function() {
     var mydiv = $( ".mydiv" );
     val = val + 200;

     $(".mydiv").css("animation-duration", val + "ms");
    });
```

Comment: First, you have to obtain the `currentvalue`, probably by: `$('.mydiv').css('animation-duration') * 1000;`. The reason for multiplying by 1000 is that the function by default returns timing in seconds.

Comment: i don't know where he get the ta_Ticker so i just make it simple using currentvalue to explain it.

Comment: Your code is perfect but it actually only ads 200 to the currentvalues which is in milliseconds, for example 2000ms becomes 2000200ms.  i appreciate if you can help :)

Comment: hint: use `parseInt()` function. You are now concatenating strings.